# A motivation for the definition of the inverse image of $E\subset Y$ under a mapping $f:X\to Y$

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying the book "Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications" by Gerald B. Folland.

The author defines the inverse image of $E\subset Y$ under a mapping $f:X\to Y$ as follows.$$f^{-1}(E)=\{x:f(x)\in E\}$$

This definition frustrates me a bit because we can have inverse image for $E\subset Y$ such that there exists $y\in E$ for which there is no $x\in X$ satisfying $y=f(x)$.

For example, for the function $f(x)=x^2$ the inverse image of $\{-1, 4\}$ is $\{-2,2\}$.

I would've also been frustrated if one defined inverse image for any set $E$.

I would've defined inverse image for $E\subset f(X)$ where $f(X)$ is the range of $f$.

Could anyone give a motivation for defining inverse image for $E\subset Y$?

Comment: The inverse image can be the empty set.

Comment: You are right. For example, for the function $f(x)=x^2$ the inverse image of $\{-1\}$ is $\{\}$. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason *not* to define it for every subset $E \subset Y$. It would be more cumbersome to have to check that $E \subset f(X)$ before you take $f^{-1}(E)$. For instance, one characterization of continuity is this: $f:X \to Y$ is continuous if whenever $E \subset Y$ is open in $Y$, $f^{-1}(E)$ is open in $X$. This holds even for $E \not\subset Y$, and if you insisted on only taking the portion of $E$ inside $f(X)$, i.e. $E \cap f(X)$, you might not have an open set anymore. It would really complicate things not not allow $f^{-1}(E)$ to be defined for every $E \subset Y$.

Comment: It seems I have to accept the definition as it is for now. Probably I will be able to appreciate its usefulness in near future. I

Comment: I have a strong desire to be back to your answer as soon as I learn what open set is. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're studying real analysis, you should learn very soon what an open set is. :)